# How to compare means of two sets when one set is a subset of another and the sample sizes are not

Tags: statistics

I have two sets containing citation counts for some publications. Of those sets one is a subset of the another. That is, subset contains some exact citation counts appearing on the other set. e.g.

```
Set1    Set2 (Subset)
50      50
24      24
12      -
5       5
4       4
43      43
2       -
2       -
1       -
1       -
```

So I want to decide if the numbers from the subset are good enough to represent set1? On this matter:

1. I have intended to apply student t-test but i could not be sure how
   to apply it. The reason is that the sets are dependent so I could
   not apply unpaired t-test requiring both sets must come from
   independent populations. On the other hand, paired t-test also does
   not look suitable since sample sizes must be equal.
2. In case of an outlier should I remove it? To me it is not logical
   since it is not normally an outlier but a publication is cited quite a
   lot so it belongs to the same sample. How to deal with such cases?
   If I do not remove it, it causes the variance to be too big
   affecting statistical tests...Is it a good idea to replace it with
   median instead of mean since citation distributions generally tend
   to be highly skewed?

How could I remedy this issue?

Comment: Perhaps this question fits best at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes @AiltonAndradedeOliveira I have already asked there but since i could not get any respond for a long time I ve just decided to try my chance here:)

Comment: I do not understand your question very well.  Do you ask a question like: "is the mean of Set2 sufficiently similar to the mean of Set1?"  (or any other statistic besides the mean.)  If this is the case, your Set2 is a sample from the population Set1.  About your case 2: the citations may be power-law distributed and the variance may not exist.

Comment: @OttToomet as you said set2 is a sample from set1. How can I compare if the mean1 = mean2?

Comment: OK, so you basically need standard errors (well, confidence intervals) for sample statistics, where the sample is drawn from a finite population with no repetitions.  I don't know much about such sampling, but I suspect if size of set2 << size of set1, then the usual formulas are good enough.